# Are linear extensions of continuous functions also continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, continuity

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $\mathcal{F}:=\{u_j\mid j\in J\}\subset H$ be compact subset of linearly independent vectors (that is, the elements of any finite subselection of $\mathcal{F}$ are linearly independent). Set $V:=\mathrm{span}(\mathcal{F})$.

It is clear that any function $f : \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ admits a unique linear extension $\bar{f} : V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

**Question:** If $f : \mathcal{F}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous (wrt. the subspace topology on $\mathcal{F}$), does this imply that $\bar{f}$ is continuous?

(If necessary, it may be assumed that $J$ is countable.)

Comment: I assume you mean $f$ to be linear, too. Consider the equivalent question: can an unbounded linear function have a continuous restriction to a sub space? The answer here is easy: any unbounded linear restricted to a finite dimensional sub space is (uniformly) continuous

Comment: @Nick Thanks for your comment. However, I don't mean $f$ to be linear, nonlinear $f$ are very much allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me begin with some notation, $e_j$ will denote the sequence, which is $1$ on the j-th term and $0$ otherwise.

Let $H = \ell_2$ and $u_j = e_1 + \frac{1}{j} e_{j+1}$ for $j \geq 2$ and $u_1 = e_1$. It is easy to see that $\{u_j\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is compact (it is a convergent sequence with its limit) and linearly independent.

Then $V = \operatorname{span}\{u_j\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}} = \operatorname{span}\{e_j\}_{j \in \mathbb{N}}$ is the space of all finitely supported sequences, that is sequences with only finitely many nonzero terms.

Let $f(u_j) = 1 + \frac{1}{j}$, for $j \geq 2$, and $f(u_1) = 1$. Then clearly $f$ is continuous, and hence uniformly continuous (as every continuous function defined on a compact space is uniformly continuous). Further, this $f$ satisfies $f(e_j) = 1$, $j \in \mathbb{N}$.

Now, let $\overline{f}$ be the linear extension to $V$. By linearity, $\overline{f}$ is the summing functional, that is $\overline{f}((x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n$ for any sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in V$. But this functional is not bounded (try plugging in the sequence whose elements are $(1,\frac{1}{2},\dots, \frac{1}{n},0,\dots)$ - it is bounded in the $\ell_2$ norm, but has unbounded $\overline{f}$-values).

A comment is in order: your condition on $f$ will make $\overline{f}$ bounded on a basis of $V$, and hence on its symmetric convex hull. But in order for $\overline{f}$ to be continuous, it needs to be bounded on the whole unit ball, which is in general a bigger set.

Comment: Out of interest, how is the *symmetric* convex hull defined?

Comment: Symmetric convex hull of a set $A$ is just the convex hull of $A \cup -A$ :)